# Intersection and Union of two sorted lists (return type)

Tags: c++, list, return

This code is for finding the intersection and union of two sorted lists. The sorted list in inherited from a list class with all the basic functions. The main question is what is the return type of the function.
Is it a pointer to a list or the list itself? How would i display the contents of that "pointer".

```
template <typename Object>
class sorted_list : public List<Object>{
    friend sorted_list<Object>*& slUnion( const sorted_list<Object>& list1, const sorted_list<Object> & list2){
        auto i=list1.begin();
        auto j=list2.begin();
        sorted_list<Object> un;
        static sorted_list<Object>* newlist=&un;
        while(i!=list1.end() && j!=list2.end()){
            if(*i<*j){
                un.push_back(*i);
                i++;
            }
            else if(*i>*j){
                un.push_back(*j);
                j++;
            }
            else{ //if equal
                un.push_back(*i);
                i++; j++;
            }
        }
        while(i!=list1.end())
            un.push_back(*i++);
        while(j!=list2.end())
            un.push_back(*j++);
        return newlist;
    }
};
```

When the program runs, the "un" in main points to NULL.

```
int main(){
    sorted_list<int> l1;
    int i=1;
    while(i<10){
        l1.push_back(i++);
    }
    sorted_list<int>l2;
    int j=1;
    while(j<10){
        l2.push_back(j);
        j+=2;
    }
    sorted_list<int> *un = slUnion(l1,l2);
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection?

Comment: Note: `static sorted_list<Object>* newlist=&un;` is not going to keep `un` in scope and alive after the function exits. You don't want to have to deal with the `un`dead, so consider returning by value.  RVO will probably keep the costs down, but if it doesn't it's still a better option than returning a local.

Answer (score 1):

You should typically return by value, i.e. `sorted_list<Object>`. Newer versions of cpp guarantee you that they will not actually make a copy.

What you are doing right now is wrong, because it has undefined behavior. You are using `un`, which is on the function stack, and return a pointer to it. By the time the function returns `un` has gone out of scope and the memory location can have been reused. Just completely remove the `newlist` pointer and return `un` instead.

You also seem to be confused about classes, methods and functions. As it is, your method does not have to be inside a class, or, since it does not seem to use class state, it can be static, if inside a class. It also does not seem like it would have to be a friend. If you wanted to write this as a member-function, it would look sth like this:

```
sorted_list<Object>& unionWith(const sorted_list<Object>& rhs) {
  // merge this and rhs w deduplication into temp, then swap temp with this
  ...

  return *this;
}
```

I think what is likely your problem, is that you don't assign `&un` to `newlist`, but that you initialize `newlist` with `&un`. Initialization is only performed once for a function-static variable, so future iterations of your method just skip that line and the pointer points to where the original version of `un` was. Try putting the assignment on a different line. That should fix your immediate issue, but the solution with the static  pointer is still really bad, because the pointer is shared by all instances.

Comment: The question initially asks to implement that function which is in an inherited class and is a friend function with a return value *&. Hence, why I'm confused about how i should be returning a list or a list pointer

Comment: The type in the signature is a reference to a pointer to a sorted_list<Object>. You can use that just like a pointer. This signature is pretty weird FYI.

Comment: nitpick: `union` is a keyword, so the function needs a new name